# cant download dataframe to excel from exe of tkinter Python

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I tried to convert my data analyst project to GUI using Tkinter library.
I build the entire project on PyCharm and everything worked.

so I tried to convert my project to exe.

on the terimal I typed this code:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --icon="icon.png" gui.py
```

And on the dist folder, I copy my asset folder to the new folder with the exe (so all the images can work, and they did - my exe project work)
all the graph display works.
Here is my dist folder:
[image: The image of dist folder]

although when I try to execute my DataFrame to excel project I got an error on the terminal of the exe project:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback                                                                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        
File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__                                                                      
File "gui.py", line 180, in <lambda>                                                                                    
File "Analyst.py", line 64, in print_sum                                                                                
File "Analyst.py", line 10, in download_df_to_csv_local                                                                 
File "pandas\core\generic.py", line 2345, in to_excel                                                                   
File "pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 888, in write                                                                   
File "pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 49, in __init__                                                             
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'`
```

As you can see the problem was on my file Analyst.py on the function:

```
def download_df_to_csv_local(df):
    token_id = secrets.token_urlsafe(6)
    df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\עידן\Desktop\all_connected' + token_id + '.xlsx', index=False)
```

I have to mention that everything worked on my PyCharm, only when I compiled to exe I got errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when there is an import that is not visible or directly imported in the main file which is being converted to exe. As pandas uses the module openpyxl to read and write to different excel formats.

You can use the `--hidden-import MODULE-NAME` option in pyinstaller.

The command will look like this:
`pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import openpyxl --icon="icon.png" gui.py`

Answer (score 0):

I solve my own error by follow this way:

1. On the terminal make sure that you are on the on the project path.
2. Type `pip install openpyxl`
3. Execute the file to exe by type `pyinstaller --onefile --icon="icon.png" gui.py`

Comment: what was your exact problem with openpyxl module? Does not pyinstaller install it by default. I have problem like, exe file saves to excel file which is in temporary folder, the file in bundle folder stays unchanged